# Linked Table Transaction

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Parents and Children and they are trivial for this question.
Parents (id, name)
Children (id, name, fkey parent_id)

Is there a way to create both a parent record and a child record in a single transaction?

Comment: no. an insert query can target a single table only. You have to insert into the parent table, then do a separate insert into the child table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in a single transaction although not in a single insert instruction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  INSERT INTO Parents ...
  INSERT INTO Children ...
COMMIT
```